# How to install jVi plugin in jME3 SDK?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to install [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/jvi-main.html) into [jME3 SDK](http://jmonkeyengine.org/downloads/?did=1). When I attempt to manually add them from within the SDK (via tools->plugins->downloaded->add plugins->install), I am unable to press 'Next,' and am told I need a number of APIs to be installed:

```
Some plugins require plugin MIME Lookup API to be installed.
The plugin MIME Lookup API is requested in version >= 1.22.1 but only 1.22 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin UI Utilities API to be installed.
The plugin UI Utilities API is requested in version >= 7.31.1 but only 7.31 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin Dialogs API to be installed.
The plugin Dialogs API is requested in version >= 7.20.1 but only 7.20 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin Nodes API to be installed.
The plugin Nodes API is requested in version >= 7.21.1 but only 7.21 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin Text API to be installed.
The plugin Text API is requested in implementation version 201107282000.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin Utilities API to be installed.
The plugin Utilities API is requested in version >= 8.15.1 but only 8.15 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin Lookup API to be installed.
The plugin Lookup API is requested in version >= 8.8.1 but only 8.8 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues 
Some plugins require plugin Window System API to be installed.
The plugin Window System API is requested in version >= 6.40.1 but only 6.40 was found.  The following plugin is affected:       jVi: NB-7.0.1 patch for undo related issues  Some plugins not installed to avoid potential installation problems.
```

These APIs do not appear to be available in either the 'Available' or the 'Installed' tabs. jME3 SDK is based off of I know not what version of netbeans. The about section of the jme3 SDK just tells me I am using jME3 SDK 3.0beta. I tried opening up some of jars and had a poke around, but couldn't find much pertinent information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I just found the solution. When manually installing from the jVi zip file in jME3 SDK, you should only select the following modules:

> jVi Core
>
> jVi for NetBeans
>
> jVi Help
>
> NB-jVi-SPI

Hope this helps anybody having the same problem!!